# Memory space usage of for(i in 1:1000)

Tags: r, for-loop, iterator

Does `for(i in 1:1000)` actually allocate a 1000 words long space for the vector, or it acts like `for(i=1;i<=1000;++i)` in C?

To clarify the question, let me show two possible implementations of `for(i in seq(1000))DoSomething(i)`

First Implementation:

> Allocate a space in memory of length 1000, label it as v
>
> Write 1,2,3...,1000 to that memory region
>
> Allocate a space in memory of length 1 for the counter, label it as c
>
> Allocate a space in memory of length 1 for i
>
> Set c=0
>
> loopstart:Read v[c] from memory, write the value to i
>
> Invoke DoSomething, with i as its argument
>
> Set c=c+1
>
> If c<1000 then goto loopstart

Second Implementation:

> Allocate a space in memory of length 1 for i
>
> Set i=1
>
> loopstart:Invoke DoSomething, with i as its argument
>
> Set i=i+1
>
> If i<=1000 then goto loopstart

The second one is much more efficient than the first one in terms of space complexity. My question is, which one is closer to the real implementation?

Comment: Useful for understanding: `i <- c(); for(x in seq(10)){i <- c(i, x); print(object.size(i))}` ...but don't write code like that. If you need to use a `for` loop (which you usually don't, thanks to vectorization, `lapply`, etc.), preallocate a vector of the appropriate size.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for the reply. But I think you've misunderstood my question. I have edited it to clarify.

Comment: The former, because `1:1000` is calling `:` which allocates a vector.

Comment: You should study `help("for")`: "**The seq in a for loop is evaluated at the start of the loop**; changing it subsequently does not affect the loop. If seq has length zero the body of the loop is skipped. Otherwise the variable var is assigned in turn the value of each element of seq. You can assign to var within the body of the loop, but this will not affect the next iteration. When the loop terminates, var remains as a variable containing its latest value."

Comment: @Roland Yeah. I just think it would be better for R interpreter to optimize away the vector, or use a more economic internal structure for vectors like 1:1000.

Comment: @elflyao There is work being done on a JIT compiler (see the compiler package). I don't know if it already optimizes this away, but I know that `for` loops are optimized somehow. However, keep in mind that `for` loops are not that important in R. Usually there is an alternative with much better (by orders of magnitude) performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you mean now, and the news is bad (according to my tests).

Consider the following code, run through `profvis`:

[image]

We create the vector `v`, to show what it looks like when a vector *is* created, then clear the RAM and run an empty `for` loop. Having a look at the Memory usage, it certainly appears that R creates a vector in memory.

Out of interest, we can introduce a `while` loop into the ring, since it behaves more like your "second implementation":

[image]

Note the same tests again, but we now have a `while` loop in there as well. Notice the memory allocation for the while loop has both positive and negative attributes, implying that so much memory was allocated *and* cleared during the process. I'd assume this is because of the way `i` is recreated on each iteration (ie: a copy made, then the original overwritten by the copy). It looks to me like `while` is behaving as your "second implementation" as expected, but `for` is behaving as your "first implementation".

Keep in mind the reasons behind this. `for` can be used to allocate not only a sequence vector, but can be used to iterate over *any* vector. For example:

```
words <- c( "hey", "there", "how", "are", "you" )
for( i in words ) {
    print( i )
}

# [1] "hey"
# [1] "there"
# [1] "how"
# [1] "are"
# [1] "you"
```

That would be difficult to achieve without allocating that vector at some point.